# Find and return exact matches (duplicates) in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I've been googling a lot and tried to use different filters for arrays and such, to no avail.

I have an array with a string like so:

```
var foo = ['1X31UX11','X3U11X1','33X11U12'];
```

Is there a way to check every string against each other in the array, and if there's an exact match (i.e. the exact same order of characters) it prints how many times the particular string occurs & also prints the string in question?

Comment: Yes, it's possible (and in fact quite easy to write yourself) - please show your attempts and explain what the problem with them is

Comment: What's the expected result look like?

Comment: It's a medium sized dataset w. 2-300 entries, so I would like to collect the duplicate entries in an array or object like so: 

['string 1' : 15 times, 'string 2: 12 times,  'string 3:  8 times]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function arrayRepeats(array) {
    var returnObject = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (returnObject[array[i]]) {
            returnObject[array[i]]++;
        } else {
            returnObject[array[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return returnObject;
}

var foo = ['1X31UX11','X3U11X1','33X11U12'];
console.log(arrayRepeats(foo));
var bar = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 31, 3, 1, 5, 4, 1];
console.log(arrayRepeats(bar));
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! It makes a lot of perfect now! I was on a similar approach but pretty much forgot the else-statement (rendering the function pretty much useless)

Comment: @user2868900 you can accept an answer to show people who visit your question which answer woked for you

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to collect the the number of appearances of each string into an object:

```js
var foo = ['1X31UX11','X3U11X1','33X11U12', '1X31UX11'];

var result = foo.reduce(function(count, str) {
  count[str] = (count[str] || 0) + 1;
  
  return count;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```